# Permuting numpy's 2d array indexes

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, multidimensional-array

are there any numpy function or clever use of views to accomplish what the following function do?

```
 import numpy as np

 def permuteIndexes(array, perm):
     newarray = np.empty_like(array)
     max_i, max_j = newarray.shape
     for i in xrange(max_i):
         for j in xrange(max_j):
             newarray[i,j] = array[perm[i], perm[j]]
     return newarray
```

That is, for a given permutation of the indexes of the matrix in a list `perm`, this function calculates the result of applying this permutation to the indexes of a matrix.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
def permutateIndexes(array, perm):
    return array[perm][:, perm]
```

---

Actually, this is better as it does it in a single go:

```
def permutateIndexes(array, perm):
    return array[np.ix_(perm, perm)]
```

To work with non-square arrays:

```
def permutateIndexes(array, perm):
    return array[np.ix_(*(perm[:s] for s in array.shape))]
```

Comment: hummm! I must to learn how to use those views properly. Is there any guide around?

Comment: @RafaelS.Calsaverini definitely read the [Tentative NumPy Tutorial](http://www.scipy.org/Tentative_NumPy_Tutorial) if you haven't already.